# consumer offset update for batch message need example

Tags: apache-kafka

I would like my consumer to update `ZK` about its offsets once I received 10MB of messages total size.

Is there a way to customize my consumer to update offset after I got 10MB message?

Answer (score 0):

First, set `auto.commit.enable` property to `false` to disable auto commit behavior of consumers. Then keep the size of messages you've got so far to some variable, and if it reaches to 10MB, commit the offset using `ConsumerConnector` interface's `commitOffsets` method. Then the offset in ZK will be updated. After that reset the size variable to 0.